How to install AWS NICE EnginFrame and its operation process
You need to install and run NICE EnginFrame, but there are currently not many references available even if you search on Google.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enginframe/latest/ag/section-installation.html I tried following the link, but an error occurred in the middle.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/set-up-an-auto-scaling-virtual-desktop-infrastructure-vdi-by-using-nice-enginframe-and-nice-dcv-session-manager.html
I am trying to install the epic content in order, but the installation does not proceed.
If there is anyone who has handled or installed NICE EnginFrame, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me which document to refer to to install it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/set-up-an-auto-scaling-virtual-desktop-infrastructure-vdi-by-using-nice-enginframe-and-nice-dcv-session-manager.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enginframe/latest/ag/section-installation.html#optimizing-jdk-options
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enginframe/latest/ag/running.html

I'm glad you're posting references but you're not posting any errors. What part is failing, what are the errors, and does this have anything to do with programming? See how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.
